# Find Dedekind cut for $3-\sqrt2$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to give a Dedekind cut in $R\ge 0$ corresponding with $3-\sqrt2$. I know how to do it for just the $\sqrt2$ but does this follow the same reasoning?

Comment: Why not write out how you do it for $\sqrt2$, and see whether it goes through (maybe with some small adjustments) for $3-\sqrt2$?

Answer (score 2):

$x^2 - 6x +7$ is a rational polynomial that both $3-\sqrt{2}$ and $3+\sqrt{2}$ are roots of, and as a function is negative in-between ($x=2$ lies in this interval), and $>0$ for $x < 3-\sqrt{2}$ and $x > 3 + \sqrt{2}$. (I found this polynomial by multiplying out $(x-(3-\sqrt{2}))(x-(3+\sqrt{2}))$, which works as the two roots are conjugate in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$; a standard algebra trick)

So  we can describe the left half of the Dedekind cut for $3-\sqrt{2}$ as

$$\{x \in \mathbb{Q}: x^2 - 6x + 7 > 0 \land x < 2 \}$$

Comment: Very nice technique +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thx. This kind of thing of course only works for nice algebraic  irrationals, most irrationals will not have such a nicely describable Dedekind cut.